# Taylor series evaluation

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I have the following Taylor series and I don't know how to get to the correct answer. The series is:

> $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}p\frac{i^nt^n}{n!},~~p \in \mathbb{R} $$

My reasoning is:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}p\frac{i^nt^n}{n!} = p\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(it)^n}{n!} = pe^{it} $$

$~$

However, the correct answer is $(1 - p) + pe^{it}$. Would someone please show the correct way of evaluating this series? Thanks.

**Edit: Adding Context**

> Let $X$ be a discrete random variable, all whose moments are given by $E(X^k) = p$, $k = 1, 2, ...$, where $0 < p < 1$. Find the characteristic function of $X$.

My solution:

$$ \varphi_X(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \varphi_X^{(n)}(0)\frac{t^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}i^nE(X^n)\frac{t^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}i^np\frac{t^n}{n!} $$

Comment: The error is in the last step of your procedure from the probability problem: you have $E[X^0]=1$, not $p$.

Comment: @Ian and where would the $-p$ come from?

Comment: They have not given you $E(X^0)$. This has to be $1$ and so your series should have been the one I suggested.

Comment: The whole term $1-p$ serves to convert the first term of the series for $pe^{it}$ i.e. $p$ into $1$ as it must be.

Comment: @Ian thanks. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.

The book answer you give is for the sum $$1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p\frac{i^nt^n}{n!}.$$

Is there something before this summation which could explain this?

Comment: I added context.